# Custom Owl Carousel - OWL.JS Pause on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I have the following slider in a Codepen working and I am trying to modify it for my website. I would like the carousel to pause on hover.

I have tried all the options on the owl slider from - autoplayHoverPause:true as in the documentation and editing the custom code. I believe there is some conflict with the autoPlaySpeed.

I have the slider working in the following [CodePen](https://codepen.io/osingh/pen/wOqrPX).

Around line 2511 there is a function that does the hover pause but i have tried to modify it with no luck.

I have also tried the following with no luck:

```
$('.owl-carousel').mouseover(function(){
   owl_product.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
})

$('.owl-carousel').mouseleave(function(){
  owl_product.trigger('play.owl.autoplay',[1000]);
 })
```

I have also tried this with no luck.:

```
'mouseleave.owl.autoplay': $.proxy(function() {
                        if (this._core.settings.autoplayHoverPause && this._core.is('rotating')) {
                                this.stop(); // Quick fix for resume play on mouseleave
                                this.play();
                        }
                }, this),
```

Any help woud be greatly appreciated as i believe I am starting to loose my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `autoplayHoverPause:true` option.
See more here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html